# How can I simplify multiple "append"?

Tags: python, pandas, list, append

I'm doing nested looping. However, my code is kind of messy because I use a lot of append list. I just simplify my parameters to make them more comfortable to look. Is there any method to simplify the codes? Thanks a lot.

Basically, `feature(person, term)[0]` is a def(), and it return a tuple of value, like this

```
(0     0.019130
 1     0.011670
 2     0.012957
 3     0.015715
Name: Vol, dtype: float64,
(0     0.019130
 1     0.011670
 2     0.012957
 3     0.015715
 Name: Fluc, dtype: float64)
```

Edit

—————

Let’s say we just want to loop this random_num()(a tuple) multiple times. And let’s forget `feature(person, term)[0]` , this is being replaced by `random_num()`

```py
volume_df = pd.DataFrame()
fluc_df = pd.DataFrame()
column = ["apple", "bababa", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"]
import random
def random_num():
    nums = []
    for i in range(10):
        nums.append(random.random())
    nums = tuple(nums)
    return nums

for leg in range(1, 2):
    volume_per = []
    fluctuation_per = []

    for person in range(1, 3):
        volume_note = []
        fluctuation_note = []
        for term in range(1, 7):
            volume_df = random_num()
            fluctuation_df = random_num()
            
            volume_note.append(volume_df)
            fluctuation_note.append(fluctuation_df)
  
        volume_per.append(volume_note)
        fluctuation_per.append(fluctuation_note)
        
    volume_df = [pd.DataFrame(i).T.set_axis(column[0], axis=1) for i in volume_per]   
    fluc_df = [pd.DataFrame(i).T.set_axis(column[0], axis=1) for i in fluctuation_per]
```

I feel like it's terrible if I have hundred index in `feature(person, term, leg)[index]`, and the reason is that I have so many append.

Comment: Have you considered list comprehensions?

Comment: There's likely a pandas-native solution without explicit loops. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BernardinoSassolide'Bianchi I’ve seen that document, but i don’t know how to do it in here. The whole example is about to read the if statement inside the loop :) Could you give an example in these codes, thanks

Comment: @timgeb Okay, let me think of it. Because it’s hard to minimize it.

Comment: @timgeb I edited it (to a simple code), hope it could be solved